# Where do nuclear gyromagnetic ratios come from?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Let's take $^1$H and $^{15}$N for example. Both have 1/2 nuclear spin because of an unpaired nucleon but very different gyromagnetic ratios. For an NMR code that I'm currently developing, these numbers are hard-coded as experimental parameters. But in principle, could these values be derived from first principles at a more fundamental level, using QCD or something? Thanks.

Comment: If you have further questions after reading this come back.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_magnetic_moment

Comment: Thanks, but that article doesn't really answer why the magnetic moment is different for different nuclei with the same spin. My guess is that the answer is somewhere in the nuclear shell model, but I can't find a good reference.

Comment: [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_moment) describes how to compute magnetic moments from the shell model.

Comment: Note that $\rm^1H$ and $\rm^{15}N$ have opposite parity, so the $\rm^{15}N$ wavefunction must contain nonzero orbital angular momentum.

Comment: Thanks, I read that page and some other sources. It seems that indeed the nuclear magnetic moments are derivable from the shell model to some accuracy. The shell model itself is semi-empirical but, from what I understand, in principle derivable from deeper theories.